# hashie gem conflict while require twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hey when i try to 'require' the gem -> twitter (1.6.2) in my rails app I get an error 
`can't activate hashie (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for ["twitter-1.6.2"], already activated hashie-1.2.0 for ["instagram-0.8.4"]`. I did 'gem list' and saw this `hashie (1.2.0, 1.1.0)`. I removed the 1.1.0 version of hashie and that gave another error `RubyGem version error: hashie(1.2.0 not ~> 1.1.0)`. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look into upgrading the version of the `twitter` you're using. 1.6.2 is at least a year old. The gem is now on version 3.x and no longer has the `hashie` dependency.

If this isn't an option for you, you're really just left with forking the [`twitter`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem source, modifying the [`1.6.2`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/tree/v1.6.2) tag to suit your needs by either removing the `hashie` dependency or raising it's dependency version in [`twitter.gemspec`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/v1.6.2/twitter.gemspec), and then referring to your git fork in your `Gemfile`

```
gem "twitter", git: "git://github.com/...", "1.6.2"
```

Whether removing or raising the version restriction on the `hashie` gem dependency, you should re-run the tests for the `twitter` gem before deploying your site with this change.